# Can the HAL daemon be safely disabled for servers?

Tags: linux, lamp

I'm running a LAMP server with openSUSE 11.3 for a hobby, and wonder whether the HAL daemon have any function on such machine. So far it also seems to consume memory, and DBUS/udev can already handle hardware changes.

Is this correct, and can I just disable the HAL service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very close. OpenSUSE 11.4 (to be released very soon now) does not have HAL at all. The functionality it provides is being served up by udev now. So, I guess it depends on what version of opensuse you're running. 11.3 will probably be OK with that.

Comment: I'm on openSUSE 11.3 (updated question), so that good news :) Any idea what HAL is still used for? auto mounting disks? :P

Comment: @vdboor Mounting disks at startup is udev. Doing it after boot, such as for insertable media and *maybe* optical drives, is HAL. I think.